# WordPress site won't load. Can you help me out solve this problem?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

> **Fatal error:** Cannot redeclare wp_is_xml_request() (previously declared in /.../public_html/wp-includes/load.php:1534) in /.../public_html/wp-includes/load.php on line 1534

Comment: Gonna need a bit more than that. Did you disable plugins, ect?

Comment: What PHP version you using?

Answer (score 1):

The function wp_is_xml_request() was declared somewhere already when the app tried to declare it again at load.php:1534.  You'll need to remove or redeclare one of them. You could search your whole codebase for wp_is_xml_request() and see if it appears more than once. Possible that a plugin or template is declaring that function.  So perhaps disable all plugins and re-enable them one at a time until you find the error. Then you'll know the offending plugin (if in fact it is a plugin). If not a plugin, then you'll have to try changing themes or any other additional items which are not in the default wordpress installation.